# Finding significantly good or bad years for school's pass/fail ratio with changing class sizes

Tags: time-series, binary-data, ratio

I have yearly pass/fail ratios for 3 different schools, spanning 10 years. I want to test which years were particularly good or bad for each school. I also want to test whether any student population characteristics can account for the good or bad years. 
The data is recorded at the individual student level like this:

```
School Student Year Age SAT Pass/Fail
1      1       2000 18  1300   P
1      2       2000 17  1270   F
2      3       2000 19  1200   P
```

What kind of analysis makes the most sense for this context?

Comment: It's not clear what your data example means. For instance, are the words "School Student ... and so on" meant to be data entries followed by a bunch of numbers? And what do the numbers refer to?

Comment: Ah! Now I get it. Aside from the confusion produced by plopping the data into CV as a single row versus in a sensible tabular format, what else can you tell us about this information? Are the schools the only constant? Are the schools similar in terms of, e.g., their demographics, the # of students getting free lunches, are they all high schools, their school districts, etc.? Is student #1 always the same student within a school and can student #1 be followed through multiple, consecutive years of testing? Or is only one year available per student?

Comment: Each student appears only once, for 1 year, in 1 school- this is their final year of high school.  I am looking at yearly graduation rates, for each school.  The schools are not comparable, it's best to analyze them separately, but I'm not sure how to figure out which years were significantly good or bad for a given school.

Even advice on how to frame my question in a more concise or useful way would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to leverage some variant of hierarchical modeling. This seems like a natural approach given that students are nested within schools. The hierarchical structure would have an advantage over GLMs (treating the schools as factors in ANOVA) in that it would shrink the errors substantially. A good, education-centric introduction is Judith Singer's pdf *Using SAS PROC MIXED to Fit Multilevel Models, Hierarchical Models, and Individual Growth Models*. Forget that it has *SAS* in the title, it's just a great, brief intro to this class of HLMs, available here:

https://www.ida.liu.se/~732G34/info/singer.pdf

The difference between your model and hers is that your dependent variable is 0,1 for Pass/Fail where her DVs are grades and test scores (for the most part). In addition, depending on how "rare" failing students are, you may need to integrate zero-inflated considerations into your model. At this point, the issues do become software specific in terms of how you deal with these challenges.